# Display Account Settings for a specific account

Tags: android

Given an account type and and account name, is there a way to display the account preferences screen?    This is the screen with the delete and sync now buttons.

Note: I don't want to display the list of accounts as can be done with ACTION_SYNC_SETTINGS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been trying to do this as well, and I can get pretty close! but I suspect this action is not actually allowed. We can launch the account preferences screen, but then an error pops up with a forced-close notification.

We only need to start the following intent to launch the settings for a specific account:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.SubSettings");
i.setComponent(cn);
```

Basically, when ActivityManager starts the activity, via manually clicking on the account, the intent is:

```
01-17 11:28:39.738: I/ActivityManager(72): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cmp=com.android.settings/.SubSettings (has extras)} from pid 708
```

Compare this with the Intent sent by our approach:

```
01-17 11:23:39.740: D/SetupSync(1359): Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cmp=com.android.settings/.SubSettings }
```

HOWEVER, here's the caveat: then Android shows a forced close notification, and we can see in the logs:

```
01-17 11:23:39.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1359): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cmp=com.android.settings/.SubSettings } from ProcessRecord{415415b8 1359:org.mozilla.gecko/10044} (pid=1359, uid=10044) not exported from uid 1000
01-17 11:23:39.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1359):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1327)
01-17 11:23:39.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1359):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1281)
01-17 11:23:39.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1359):     at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:1624)
01-17 11:23:39.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1359):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
01-17 11:23:39.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1359):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3190)
01-17 11:23:39.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1359):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3297)
01-17 11:23:39.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1359):     at org.mozilla.gecko.sync.setup.activities.SetupSyncActivity.onResume(SetupSyncActivity.java:148)
01-17 11:23:39.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1359):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1154)
01-17 11:23:39.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1359):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:4539)
01-17 11:23:39.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1359):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2433)
01-17 11:23:39.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1359):     ... 12 more
```

So, what you can do is try/catch the RuntimeException, so it doesn't pop up. Seems a little sketchy, but if you want a hack, well, this achieves the desired result...

**TL;DR:
We can launch the settings for a specific account, but then the scary sorry-this-app-had-to-close dialogue pops up.**